# Convert NSString to NSDate Using NSDateFormatter

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, nsdate, nsdateformatter

trying to convert NSString to NSDate

```
NSString *startDateForCal='09-03-2016 08:00:00 AM'
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat: @"dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss a"];
NSDate * EventStart = [dateFormatter dateFromString: startDateForCal];
```

But getting mixed result as "2016-03-09 18:30:00 +0000" returning date as correct but time didn't match with string It would be welcome any suggestions

Thank you

Comment: What's your local time zone?

Comment: @Avi : My timezone IST

Comment: There is nothing wrong with your code or the output.

Comment: I edit my question. But my date format as different from string

Comment: This is not your real code. Please show real code. `NSString *startDateForCal='09-03-2016 08:00:00 AM'` cannot be your real code. There's no semicolon, and single quotes can't be used like that. Take your absolute real code and _copy and paste_ it into the question. Then take the result and _copy and paste_ it.

Answer (score 2):

it should be

```
[dateFormatter setDateFormat: @"dd-MM-yyyy hh:mm:ss a"];
```

i.e. no capital HH for hour. HH return the  Hour in 24 format
For more details [Click now](http://unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-6.html#Date_Format_Patterns)

and regarding the error in date,
 since you have set the time format wrong( as HH instead of hh), it took the time as 12:00 AM and showed it in GMT timezone(IST - 5 and half hours, so in your case 12:00 AM - 5:30 = 18:30 of previous day), i guess you haven't set the locale properly.

setting the locale(in swift),

```
dateFormatter.locale = NSLocale(localeIdentifier:"en_IN")
```

Comment: AMI replace hh instead of HH mystring "18-03-2016 11:00:00 AM " response "2016-03-18 05:30:00 +0000"

Comment: as i mentioned already, you need to set your locale properly. 11:30 - 5:30 = 5:30

Comment: No luck    set locale  [dateFormatter setLocale:[NSLocale currentLocale]];string '26-03-2016 09:00:00 AM' output : 2016-03-26 03:30:00 +0000

Comment: dude, the problem is with your current locale only, yet you assign it back. It makes no difference actually.

Comment: dateFormatter.locale = NSLocale(localeIdentifier: "en_IN")   use this in objective c. i guess u dint c my updated answer

Comment: No suggestions are needed. You're not having any problem.

Answer (score 0):

Your question makes no sense. Your goal was to obtain an NSDate from an NSString. You did that, and you did it successfully.

How you discover what that NSDate *is*, is a completely different matter. It is represented to you by default (in the console) in a certain time zone and format. But that is irrelevant; it is still the same date, and it is the correct date.

Comment: It was returning date as correct but time not proper it should be like string

Comment: The time is right. If you show your real code and your real result, you will see that your NSDate's time shown as GMT is a correct representation of your original time taken as IST.

Comment: This feels more like a comment than an answer, you're simply pointing out that OP is asking a bad question (which is true), but you don't actually provide a solution. - [From Review](http://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/11317863)